# I seem to have two Bash cursors. What's going on here?

Tags: xterm, terminal-emulator, bugs

I seem to have two Bash cursors. The initial position of what I deem the "extra" cursor seems to depend on the length of my prompt, with longer prompts causing it to start farther behind. When I type, the extra cursor falls behind by a pixel or two with each keystroke.

This is weird and hard to describe, so I made a GIF:

[image: animation showing the problem]

What's going on here? I'm using xterm 4.4.0 embedded in Theia IDE 1.3.0.

Comment: Looks like something interesting is happening with your terminal emulator displaying everything twice as you type it.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? If you install a different one, is the behavior the same in both?

Comment: Apparently just this emulator. The terminal in question is inside the web-based Theia IDE running inside a Docker container. I'll have to dig to verify, but it's probably xterm.js.

Comment: Yep, xterm 4.4.0. https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/blob/v1.0.0/packages/terminal/package.json#L11

Comment: I assume that means the answer to my question is "this is a bug in xterm 4.4.0". Right? Or is there another possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I'm experiencing this bug: https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/issues/8158

EDIT: Theia 1.4 was released sometime in the last 24 hours, and it resolves my issue.